# Swift: What is a .swift-version file?

Tags: ios, swift

I see a lot of projects have this file in their root directory:

> .swift-version

These are some examples:

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

https://github.com/TheMindStudios/SwiftyPlayer

My question is what is the purpose of this file and what is it used for?

Answer (score 7):

This seems quite similar to the practice of a .ruby-version file which instructs a version manager like rvm to pick up a particular version of ruby. But what it's doing in case of swift, I am not really sure. Here are two related scenarios that I have come across:

1. It seems that this flag is used by the cocoapods to set some target level settings on pods. Refer:

> [Cocoapods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6067)
>
> [This cocoapod pull request can also provide some clue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6068)

2. Another place I have come across it is *[swiftenv](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv)*. This is quit like rvm (or say nvm) which can help you manage multiple versions of swift.

This is not an exact answer. But I hope it provides some information.

Answer (score 4):

In the examples you provided the .swift-version file is using by [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org), but since CocoaPods 1.4.0 you should not maintain this file anymore. Use the `swift_version` attribute to specify the Swift version instead. Check this example of a .podspec file for CocoaPods 1.6.0.beta.2:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  #other attributes
  s.swift_version = '4.2'
end
```

[Here](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.4.0/) you can find more details about CocoaPods 1.4.0 release. Check the section **Swift Version DSL**.

More than that, since CocoaPods 1.7.0.beta.1 you will get a warning if you try to use .swift-version file, see [this link](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.0-beta/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is a way to mark Pods as Swift and indicate the version to use. It also seems it will trigger the CocoaDocs generation in Swift (once CocoaDocs supports that).

See the [CocoaPods CHANGELOG](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/77d6a4a562e26ad2242578f7c2582af9851e61f5/CHANGELOG.md#110rc2-2016-09-13) file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--swift-version=VERSION` option now. For example:

> pod repo push your-specs $PROJECT_NAME.podspec --swift-version=4.0

Answer (score 1):

This defines the Swift version used during *linting*. Linting validates the library builds against all the platforms it claims to. Linting can be performed separately (`pod lib lint`) or is mandatory before pushing a new version of a pod to cocoapods-trunk or your own spec repo.