# Pod lib lint Error: Warn Swift Version

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Every time I run pod lib lint file.podspec I receive this storage warning and I can't figure out how to fix it

[image]

Comment: Which CocoaPods version are you using ? Which swift version are you using in your project ?

Comment: Im using the latest version of cocoa pods, and swift 4. Can someone tell me about a '.swift-version' file??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587440/swift-what-is-a-swift-version-file

Answer (score 1):

You won't receive this warning if you are using CocoaPods 1.7.0.beta.1 or newer because the .swift-version file was deprecated, see [this link](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.0-beta/) for more details. Use the [swift_versions attribute](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#swift_versions) to specify the Swift version:

```
s.swift_versions = ['5.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.swift-version` is a file that serves as a hint for cocoapods to know which version of Swift your pod target, for the given branch/commit/tag.

The content of the file should exclusively contain the Swift version your pod targets, so `4.2` for example if you target Swift 4.2. You can easily create such a file by navigating to the podspec's folder using the Terminal app, and then write:

```sh
echo '4.2' > .swift-version
```

(replace `4.2` with the Swift version you target)

You can find an example of such a file on Sourcery's repository: https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/blob/master/.swift-version