# Swift: how to add .swift-version to to cocoapod Framework

Tags: swift, cocoapods

[image]

How can Users add **.swift-version** files to their cocoapods frame works similar to https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. 
How can developers do this and avoid this error, during pod lib init file.podspec

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pod lib lint Error: Warn Swift Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887487/pod-lib-lint-error-warn-swift-version)

Comment: The new CocoaPods pre-release version (1.4.0) allows the framework authors to specify the swift version. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.4.0.rc.1. You must be using an old version of Xcode which doesn't support Swift 3. Try adding a `.swift_version` file in your project's root path with the content `3.0`, as the error message clearly states

Comment: im Using Xcode 9.. how can I add to root path?

Comment: It says so in the error message: `echo "3.0" > .swift-version` using the terminal app while on the project's root path. You shouldn't need to do that btw, is the framework old or not maintained anymore ? Or do you have multiple toolchains in your mac ?